# how to escape escape characters in Java

Tags: java, string, equals

I have a large file that contains \' that I need to find. I've tried variations of the following but it's not working:

```
do{           
       line =  TextFileIO.readLine(bufferedReader);           
       if(line != null){
           TextFileIO.writeLine(bufferedWriter,line); 

           for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++){

              if(line.substring(i,i+1).equals("\\\'"))System.out.println("we found it " + line);

           }
        }

    }while (line != null);
```

Comment: You can use `"\\'"`., but there is no way `substring(i,i+1)` can be equal to a two-character string. Do you mean `substring(i, i+2)` ?

Comment: `string.replace( "\\", "\\\\" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to escape the single quote!

Single quotes don't need escaping because all Java strings are delimited by double quotes. Single quotes delimit *character* literals. So in a character literal, you need to escape single quotes, e.g. `'\''`.

So all you need is `"\\'"`, escaping only the backslash.

`substring(i,i+1)` cannot produce a two character string. If you are trying to get 2-character strings, you need to call with `(i,i+2)`.

Also, your for loop can be replaced by a call to `contains`.

```
if(line.contains("\\'"))System.out.println("we found it " + line);
```

Answer (score 1):

To represent a single backslash followed by an apostrophe, you can use

```
"\\'"
```

But there is no way `substring(i,i+1)` can be equal to a two-character string.

Perhaps you mean

```
if (line.substring(i, i+2).equals("\\'")) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`line.substring(i,i+1)` only contains one character, and the `for loop` can replaced by `line.indexOf("\\'") >= 0`:

```
if (line.indexOf() >= 0) {
    System.out.println("we found it " + line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\\` is an escaped `\` in Java, so I think your match string should be `"\\"`.

P.s. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here, but there appears to be more elegant, more "java-like" ways to do it than what you have here...